# Update all values in <List> primefaces

Tags: list, primefaces

I create following list. If I change any value in the list (a color) and press after my changes the button "save" all changes should be updated in the database. 
How can I do this? I can´t see any event for

```
        <c:forEach id="repeatingEmployee" varStatus="loop"
                            items="#{employeeSettingEditController.employeeUserList}"
                            var="employee">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p:outputLabel for="color_#{loop.index}"
                                    value="#{employee.mandatory.companyName}"
                                    class="col col-md-4 control-label" />
                                <div class="col col-md-6">
                                    <p:colorPicker id="color_#{loop.index}"
                                        value="#{employee.employeeSetting.colorMandatory}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that clicking the "save" button (which I don't see anywhere here) does not execute the action?

Comment: I relove it - I forget it to pass it in a h:form